# jQuery Ajax Upload File php receives array even with out content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

It's working but on every submit I receive an array even tho a file is not even added to the file input (multifile input)

```
    postData = new FormData(this); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/url",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data === "true") {
                window.location.replace("/url");
            } else {
                $(".errors").html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            swal("Der opstod en fejl");
        }
    });
```

What i get from $_FILES is the following

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

Is there a way where I can avoid this from happening?

Comment: Yes, validate that you have had a file added to the array *before* allowing the upload.

Comment: Please add the context so we can see from where you get `this`.

Comment: That's standard behavior for a file upload where no file was provided. note the error code `4` - `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`

Comment: @MarcB Issue tho is even tho i add a file it will keep having the last array with the error 4 is that normal ?

Comment: you'd have to show how you set up your html form. given the array format and you say it's a multi-upload, you could very easily have two separate file inputs and are only filling in one.

Comment: Think i found the issue now i use something called jQuery.filer

Somehow it adds an extra array it looks like hmm wondering why tho hmm hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `required` attribute to `input type="file"` element to prevent submission of `form` if no files selected by user

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do `$.ajax()` stuff
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```